# What Do Double Subscripts ([i][j]) Mean?

Tags: c++

I know this is a very vague question and possibly horribly worded, but I am a beginner in c++ and keep seeing this (BTW I copied this code off of someone's post):

```
if ( contents[i].size() >= 5 ) {
        for ( unsigned int j=3; j<4; ++j ) {
            double value = contents[i][j];
            contents[i][j] = 0.;
}
}
```

What does the "`[i][j]`" part mean in `contents[i][j] = 0.;`? I am familiar with using just one `[i]`, but I've never used two... Can anyone tell me how just using 1 `[i]` is different from using `[i][j]` and what it means to use `[i][j]`?

Sorry for the vague question, but I couldn't find an answer to this. Thanks

Comment: Look up two-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2):

`content` most likely stores an 2D array: an array of array (probably `std::vector< std::vector<double> >`, thank you @owacoder for the comment).

`contents[i]` accesses the `i`'s array of `contents`, which itself is a `std::vector<double>`, and then `contents[i][j]` acesses the `j`'s elements of the `i`'s array stored in `contents`.

Comment: Elements of `content` have member `size()`, so I would say it is a `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You have a 2 dimensional array, so you need an (width, hight) coordinates to access every element in it?

[image]

Comment: Although OP doesn't have a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a 1d array, you access the i-th element with `[i]`.

When you have a 2d array, thus a **matrix**, you access the element in i-th row and j-th column with `[i][j]`.

Comment: I did not downvote, but the OP's example is not necessarily a 2d array (probably not, since it has `size()`), and a 2d array is not necessarily a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `contents[i]` means the ith element of a container (such as an array), but it can mean whatever the designer wanted it to mean. If you write a class of your own, you can write `operator[]` for that class to do whatever you want-- and if you make it do anything other than return a reference to the ith element of a container, the people who have to deal with your code will curse your name.

So `contents[i][j]` means the jth element of the ith element of `contents. For example,`contents`might be an array of arrays of`int`(often called a 2-dimensional array), or a`vector`of arrays of`mYClass`, or a`vector`of`myContainer`, or a`myContainer`of`myOtherContainer`...

Answer (score 0):

A "double subscript" is actually two *single* subscripts. The second subscript is applied to whatever object is returned by the first.

So with `contents[i][j]` we have:

```
contents; // object taking subscript (array, vector etc...)
```

If we subscript that object to access its contents we get another object that *also* takes a subscript:

```
contents[i]; // another object taking subscript
```

So you might typically find the "double subscript" applied to a *vector* that contains *vectors* as is elements.

```
// a vector that contains vectors that each contain doubles
std::vector<std::vector<double>> contents;
```

Then:

```
contents; // returns a vector of vectors to doubles
contents[i]; // returns a vector of doubles
contents[i][j]; // returns a double
```

Useful for modelling 2 dimensional data.